# Sort WordCount Output Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to learn Flink and I am doing the basic WordCount tutorial. I was wondering how I could sort the output of a datastream so that it outputs the counts in descending order. I don't need this saved as a text file just output to the console in descending order.

The following is within the main function

```
DataStream<String> text = env.readTextFile(<PATH TO TEXT>)
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = 
     text.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
     .keyBy(0)
     .sum(1);

counts.print();
```

Right now this writes all the counts with no issues I would like to simply have the counts sorted in descending order (by the value of the count). I was trying to get this to work with .addSink() but I do not understand how to sort with this.

Inside the main function

```
counts.addSink(new CustomSink());
```

Outside the main function

```
public static final class CustomSink implements SinkFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
     public void invoke(Integer value) throws Exeception {
     }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to achieve this by using DataStream - which will output count after a new element is summed. Better using DataSet API, which likes MapReduce, it will sort the whole result set and save them to files

Comment: I don't think that the DataSet is a good suggestion, since that has been deprecated. I believe this should be possible both in the DataStream as well as the Table API.

Comment: @MartijnVisser do you have any idea how to do it in DataStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Sorting by anything other than timestamps is fundamentally incompatible with unbounded streaming.
- Sorting over bounded streams can easily be done with Flink's SQL/Table API. There isn't a good way to do this with the DataStream API.